# confused about grouping points in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why doesn't this code make lines between data at the same values of y?

```
main <- data_frame(x=rep(c(-1, 1), each=2), y = c(c(1, 1), c(2, 2)), z = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
qplot(data = main, x = x, y = z, geom="line", group=factor(y))
```

Here is what I get:

[image: original]

But I want only the points at the same level of y to be connected.

[image: grouping I want]

Comment: because of the group by argument: `qplot(data = main, x = x, y = z, geom="line")`. Here it is not needed since you have only one element per group.

Comment: More details and an example of your problem will help someone fix your issue.

Comment: because you said so, try with `qplot(data = main, x = x, y = z, group=factor(y))`, this will give you just the dots

Comment: Okay, I see that I messed up the input data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with how you defined your `y` variable. Change it to `y = c(c(1,2), c(1,2))` and things should work.

Also, if you're going to use `data_frame` be sure to add the calls to `library` to make your code reproducible (i.e., `library(dplyr)` and `library(ggplot2)`).